# Why does the OR operator misbehave?

Tags: vala

My output should be: "d s cow s moo s spam s eggs e"

if I use this code it works fine:

```
if((ts != "d")){
    ts_re.append("s");
}
```

(ts is the current string. I iterate over some strings and I want to check if it is a "d", or an "l" and "e")

When I expand the if to:

```
if((ts != "d") || (ts != "l")){
    ts_re.append("s");
}
```

the output is: "s d s cow s moo s spam s eggs e".

so it puts an "s" before the "d" and it doesn't even care about "e" but that is not the main problem.
I have a workaround for this with a switch case statement. I only want to know if I did something wrong or I found a bug in Vala?

Comment: I don't know vala but I bet you your problem is you need to use && not ||.

Comment: yeah... I feel stupid thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
if((ts != "d") || (ts != "l"))
```

That will return true for everything.  The only thing that will return true for `ts == "d"` is `"d"`, so it's the only thing that would return `false` for the left half.  Meanwhile `"d" != "l"` will return true every time.

`false || true` will return `true`.  Since it's impossible for both halves to ever return `false`, this `||` will always to return `true`.

Comment: well.. thank you for the explanation. I thought it evaluates things seperately. I didn't know this works this way.

Comment: It does evaluate them separately.  And then your OR them together.  OR returns `true` when both halves of the operator are `true` and `false` for every other scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your or is logically incorrect: if you start with the letter d in your expanded test then the first test will fail d!=d = false so the second part of the statement will be evaluated but d!=l= true so your s gets appended even though you only wanted appended if it wasn't equal to d.

I think you need to use an and operator ts is not equal to d and not equal to l and not equal t e then append an s?